# NextJS cookie token not being detected in getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cookies, next.js

I've been working through a really decent tutorial about **setting up NextJS, firebase, and react-context** to handle user authentication. Everything has been going smoothly enough until, well ... the code within my `getServerSideProps` fails to find the cookie 'token', which causes my firebase query to fail, triggering my redirect to the login page.

So, in short I can login/logout users and set a cookie token. However, when I go to pages that SSR check for the token it doesn't find anything and instead triggers my redirect.

SSR + cookie resource i'm using: https://colinhacks.com/essays/nextjs-firebase-authentication

#### page SSR request

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {

  try {
    const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
    console.log("cookies token", cookies.token); // returns empty string :(

    const token = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(cookies.token);
    // * the user is authenticated

    const { uid, email } = token;
    // ! stuff would be fetched here

  } catch (error) {
    // either the `token` cookie doesn't exist
    // or the token verification failed
    // either way: redirect to login page

    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/auth/login",
      },
      props: {} as never,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { data, params: ctx.params },
  };
};
```

#### Context + where I set the cookie

```js
export const AuthContext = createContext<{ user: firebase.User | null }>({
  user: null,
});

export function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      (window as any).nookies = nookies;
    }
    return firebaseAuth.onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      console.log(`token changed!`);
      if (!user) {
        console.log(`no token found...`);
        setUser(null);
        nookies.destroy(null, "token");
        nookies.set(null, "token", "", {});
        return;
      }

      console.log(`updating token...`);
      const token = await user.getIdToken();
      // console.log("got user token:", token);
      // console.log("got user:", user);
      setUser(user);
      nookies.destroy(null, "token");
      nookies.set(null, "token", token, {});
    });
  }, []);

  // force token refresh every 10 minutes
  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = setInterval(async () => {
      const user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      if (user) await user.getIdToken(true);
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000);

    // clean up
    return () => clearInterval(handle);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I had a project in which I used `js-cookie` for setting cookies and `nookies` for getting cookies in serverSideProps

Comment: thats funny I ended up doing exactly that same thing after troubleshooting for ages lol

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I posted my answer to this problem here: https://github.com/maticzav/nookies/issues/255

Comment: Does this work in production too? and where have you deployed it too. I can get the cookie in development mode. When I take it to production the cookie is undefined. I am using firebase cloud functions to serve the site

Comment: for production, you have to change the name of the cookie to "__session" because of this:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies